# Convert textual representation of number to integer

Tags: swift3, converters

I am using the speech API and often the input I get back will be numbers, I need to convert this into integers. For example:

> Four Hundred and Twenty Seven

Would need to be converted to

> 427

I have no idea how to do this, is there anything built into swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumberFormatter` can do that, but the string must be in a particular format

```
let numberString = "four hundred and twenty-seven"
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

formatter.number(from: numberString) // 427
```